# Choose Verticle name to start from Maven shell

Tags: vert.x

I have a Maven based Vert-x application which contains a single Java Verticle. At the moment I'm starting the application with:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```

Now I need to add another Verticle to the project. How do I choose which Verticle to start with Maven ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a DeploymentOptions in Vertx and vertx provides multiple Verticles deployment option.

Let's consider you have MainVerticle and another verticle as DemoVerticle :

```
 public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
     vertx = this.getVertx(); 

     // you can configure deployment option

  final DeploymentOptions deployOptions1 = new DeploymentOptions();

  // using below way you can deploy multiple Verticles 
   vertx.deployVerticle(DemoVerticle.class.getName(), deployOptions1 , deployResult -> {
                if (deployResult.succeeded()) {
                    LOG.info(" [SUCCESS]  --> " + deployResult.result());
                } else {
                    LOG.error(" [ERROR] --> " + deployResult.cause());
                }
            });

  }
}
```

In pom.xml you just have to define starting main class in Shade plugin, so in above example MainVerticle is deploying other Verticles

```
 <build>
  .
  .
  .
<plugins>
        <!-- Shade plugin to assemble a runnable fat jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>${main.class}</Main-Class>
                                    <Main-Verticle>com.path-of-your-package.MainVerticle</Main-Verticle>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <artifactSet>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

  .
  .
  .
  </build>
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, and apologizes for the late acknoledgement

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using a fat jar, you are most likely using Vertx Launcher

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vert_x_launcher

which allows you to define the main verticle to run